# Cannot register Azure Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to register a self hosted Azure integration runtime.
This used to work before, but suddenly the existing runtime could not connect anymore.

I already:

- Reinstalled the local runtime installation
- Removed integration runtime in Azure and created a new one
- Regenerated keys in Azure and tried key1 and key2
- Tried to install the runtime on another server
- Tried to use the Express setup from the 'Edit integration runtime' page

[image]

But when I try to register I always get the following error:
[image]

In the event log I get the following error:

```
Failed to get service token from ADF service with key ****************** and time cost is: 0.1628846 seconds, the error code is: InvalidGatewayKey, activityId is: 445deaef-dcd5-44c9-9123-703b81b35f3f and detailed error message is Processed HTTP request failed.
.

   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DIAgentHost.NamedPipeControllers.NamedPipeGatewayClientController.AttachGatewayNode(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DIAgentHost.NamedPipeServer.MapNamedPipeRequestToController(String requestTemplate, NamedPipeStreamString ss, NamedPipeDataContract`1 result, String temp)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.DIAgentHost.NamedPipeServer.PipeServerThread(Object data)
.
```

So here there is mention of 'InvalidGatewayKey' and 'Processed HTTP request failed'

I couldn't find any useful information on these errors, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the only solution was to create a new data factory and delete the old one.
No idea why the initial suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else have this problem, it may be that your ADF is erroneously configured to use private endpoint instead of public endpoint.

The error reported here is similar to what is documented in [Unable to register IR authentication key on Self-hosted VMs due to private link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/security-and-access-control-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#unable-to-register-ir-authentication-key-on-self-hosted-vms-due-to-private-link).